# This keyword issue?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, class

I asked this question earlier but the formatting wasnt too helpful so im reposting. The logic that I wanted to implement was everytime the button is clicked, the value from the input boxes goes to the addInventory function, creates a new Album, and pushed the newly created object to the products array. At the end of the logic, there is a FOR OF loop that invokes the gridChild function and creates a new div box for every element in the array.

The issue is that whenever I click the button, nothing happens and also the THIS keyword is undefined. The new object doesnt get pushed into the array and only works when the addInventory function is a called manually.

```js
"use strict";

// DIV NESTING USING ONLY JS
const app = document.querySelector(`.app`);

const div = `<div class="grid-child">
                </div>`;
const gridContainer = `<div class="grid-container"></div>`;

// New products will be pushed in here
let products = [];

const gridParent = function() {
  // app.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, gridContainer);
  app.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, gridContainer);
}

gridParent();
const gridContainerDiv = document.querySelector(`.grid-container`);

const gridChild = function() {
  gridContainerDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, div);
}

// UI logic for product form 
// Will create a new album object 
// Need to use a prototype and class inheritance so the component is reusable and applicable for different 
// types of products.

class Album {
  constructor(title, artist, price) {
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.price = price;
  }
}

const addInventory = (title, artist, price) => {
  const newAdd = new Album(title, artist, price);
  products.push(newAdd);
  console.log(this);
};

// THIS WORKS, ADDS TO THE PRODUCT ARRAY NO PROBLEM
// 
addInventory(`Internet`, `Donald Glover`, 15);
addInventory(`Black Pumas`, `Black Pumas`, 31);

const productName = document.getElementById(`product-name`);
console.log(productName);
const productPrice = document.getElementById(`product-price`);
console.log(productPrice);
const inputBtn = document.getElementById(`inputBtn`);
console.log(inputBtn);

// THIS DOESNT WORK, THE THIS KEYWORD IS UNDEFINED AND DOES NOT CALL THE ADDINVENTORY FUNCTION
inputBtn.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addInventory(productName.value, ` `, +productPrice.value);
  console.log(this);
})

console.log(products);

// Product list mutation needs to happen before the loop function 
// so that data will be the most updated version everytime

// A div box will be created for every element in the product array
for (const everyElement of products) {
  gridChild();
  console.log(everyElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Product div creator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="module" defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">
  </div>
  <div class="inventory-gui">

    <input type="text" id="product-name" name="product-name" data-product="info"><br>
    <input type="number" id="product-price" name="product-price" data-product="info"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="inputBtn">Make a new item</button>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be in the event listener function?

Comment: What are you expecting to see when you do `console.log(this)`? Arrow functions inherit `this` from the containing scope.

Comment: How can you tell if the object is being added to the array? You don't log products after pushing?

Comment: Why don't you do `console.log(products)` after calling `addInventory()`?

Answer (score 0):

The script is doing what it is supposed to do.

```
const addInventory = (title, artist, price) => {
  const newAdd = new Album(title, artist, price);
  products.push(newAdd);
  console.log(this);
};
addInventory(`Internet`, `Donald Glover`, 15);
```

In the above script the `this` keyword will be undefined because `addInventory` is an arrow function and you are using `strict mode`.

```
inputBtn.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addInventory(productName.value, ` `, +productPrice.value);
  console.log(this);
})
```

The callback of event listener has access to the `addInventory` function so it will be called when the button is clicked. `this` keyword will be undefined here because it is an arrow function.

```
`console.log(products);`
```

I think you are expecting the above line to execute again when you click on the button. When you click on the button only the callback given to event listener gets executed not the whole script. If you need to access the updated products array you can in the callback like after calling the `addInvetory` function.
See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-allen-s2gzo?file=/src/index.js) sandbox for what I'm trying to say.

Comment: If the script is working how it is supposed to, there should be another div box that gets created when the event listener is invoked which its not.

Comment: A newly created object from the Album class should have been added to the products array but it isnt doing that.

Comment: Because you have not implemented any logic of creating a new div in the callback of event listener. How it will create the new div? You have implemented that logic outside of the callback (in the global execution context) that will run only for the first time.

Comment: That makes sense. I actually put a console log for the products in the event listener and its updating me that new products are being inputted. Thank you all!